# How to quickly select items that meet a criterion on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have two excel spreadsheets. One has hundreds of names and emails (the names aren't sorted properly and include people who will not be receiving an email), and another with hundreds of names that need to have emails sent to them. On the excel spreadsheet with names and emails, the emails are in the adjacent column to the names. Is there a way to quickly copy the emails of people who will be receiving an email?

Comment: This is `VLOOKUP`. Sort the sheet with names&emails, and on the sheet with just names, write a `VLOOKUP` to get the email associated with that name.

Comment: @Alex M Thanks, this is close to what I need. However, I'm looking for something that can get every email associated with every name on the sorted spreadsheet at the same time (the names and emails have 500 people, there are 200 people that need an email; I need their emails from the unsorted spreadsheet using the names from the sorted one).

Comment: Yup. That'll do it.

Comment: Oh, will it? Thanks!